# Error null value in entry fakeoutputdirectory=null?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-embedded-api

When I try to run my app on android studio, I get an error that says:

```
Error null value in entry: fakeOutputDirectory = null
```

I have tried deleting the .gradle folder but it doesn't help.

Note: I am running on the built in avd emulator

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the gradle directory via Terminal using

```
rm -r .gradle/
```

Before building it straight away, I **cleaned the project first** and then tried to build. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting .gradle folder from project directory,check and update the gradle to the matching version. Then perform clean build

Answer (score 0):

This solution not useful for this question but it may help the people who are working on `Cordova`

Same problem i've faced in `Cordova` and solved by using following commands

**Remove android platform**

```
cordova platform remove android
```

**Add platform again**

```
cordova platform add android
```

or

```
cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```